# Execution failed for task ':app:minifyDebugWithR8'. > java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, proguard, android-r8, jacorb

I'm using a jacorb library in my project and when i launch the build apk i get this error .
Can someone show us how to fix this error ?
please help .

Answer (score 0):

try add JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 to you app build.gradle

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

maybe help you to fix the problem, just maybe. you can try.